# Using jQuery, how can I remove a select option without an ID or class name?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, drop-down-menu

Using jQuery, I'd like to remove `(None)` as an option from a dropdown. The dropdown does not have an ID or class so I have been trying to target the SharePoint column `Parent Item` by using `$("select[title='Parent Item']")`. However, I'm not sure how I can combine this with `option[value='(None)'].remove()`.

I have tried:

`$("select[title='Parent Item'] option[value='(None)']").remove()`,

`$("(select[title='Parent Item'])[value='(None)']").remove()`,

and simply

`$("option[value='(None)']").remove();`

with no success.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the HTML? I suspect that `(None)` is not a value, but a label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `$('select[title="Parent Item"] option:contains(None)').remove();` ?

Comment: No prob. The issue was what @31piy mentioned in the comment: "(None)" is the text, not the actual `value` attribute of the `option` tag. By using "contains" you can work with the text.